# mysql regular expression for exact word match

Tags: mysql, regex

I want regular expression for exact word match for `mysql` select query. If i have below string from database

```
string :  my name is amit patel with surname amitnindroda
```

Now i want to match whole word `amit` from above string then it should find exact word `amit` and it should not find match from `amitnindroda`. Please suggest regular expression for mysql query

Comment: `[[:<:]]amit[[:>:]]`..the weird  looking thing in starting and ending is word boundary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP Keyword` and the `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` word-boundary markers:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename 
WHERE keywords REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]'
```

**Example:**

*Input*

```
id  name
1   my name is admin in userwindow
2   my name is user in adminWindow
```

*Query:*

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.name REGEXP '[[:<:]]admin[[:>:]]'
```

*Output:*

```
 id  name
 1   my name is admin in userwindow
```

So You can see here above query is searching word `'admin'` only.

Comment: Hello, Any idea for search brackets like "ABC(Apple)". It breaks when having brackets.

Comment: Yes @RajuSingh , You can use REGEXP '[[:<:]]ABC(Apple)[[:>:]]'